# What is the value of this summation in Big O terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, algorithms, asymptotics

I am trying to do an analysis for the cost of n inserts into a hashtable datastructure and I have a factor like the one below:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\lg {(n-1)}\rfloor} 2^i$$

What will be the Big O of this summation above ?

Comment: did you mean to have the exponent of $2$ different than the index of summation?

Comment: @robjohn it was a typo.fixed it . thnanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\lg {(n-1)}\rfloor}2^i
&=2^{\lfloor\lg {(n-1)}\rfloor+1}-1\\
&\le2(n-1)+1\\[9pt]
&=2n-1
\end{align}
$$